# Collapsing Infinite Integrals

Tags: integration

I'm looking into repeated integrals [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatedIntegral.html) on Wolfram's Mathworld and I can't seem to figure why it is that the following is true:

> \begin{align} \underbrace{\int
>  ...\int_0^x}_{n}f\left(x\right)\:\underbrace{dx...dx}_{n}& =
>  \int_0^x\frac{f\left(t\right)\left(x-t\right)^{n-1}\:dt}{\Gamma\left(n\right)}.
>  \tag{1} \end{align}

I understand the first part, however, s. th. 
\begin{align}
F\left(x\right)=\int f\left(x\right)\:dx=\int_0^x f\left(t\right)\:dt;\:\:F\left(0\right)=0.\tag{2}
\end{align}
It states that
\begin{align}
D^{-n}f\left(x\right)=\underbrace{\int\dots\int_0^x}_{n}f\left(x\right)\underbrace{dx\dots dx}_{n},\tag{3}
\end{align}
and since I know that all of the lower bounds are always $F\left(0\right)=F\left(F\left(0\right)\right)=\dots=0$, that part disappears -- which makes sense. What I don't understand is the collection of the upper bounds.

After the first integration then, I would have
\begin{align}
\underbrace{\int\dots\int_0^x}_{n-1}F\left(x\right)\:\underbrace{dx\dots dx}_{n-1}=\underbrace{\int\dots\int_0^x}_{n-2}\left(\int_0^x F\left(x\right)\:dx\right)\:\underbrace{dx\dots dx}_{n-2},\tag{4}
\end{align}
But what does the interior of the parenthesis equate to? Surely it is not $F\left(F\left(x\right)\right)$. How do they arrive at $\left(1\right)$?

Thank you for your time,

---

Edit:

Let $n=1$,
\begin{align}
\int_0^x f\left(x\right)\:dx & = F\left(x\right)-F\left(0\right)=F\left(x\right).\tag{5}
\end{align}
Now let $n=2$, therefore
\begin{align}
\int_0^x\int_0^x f\left(x\right)\:dx\:dx & = \int_0^x\left[F\left(x\right)-F\left(0\right)\right]\:dx=\int_0^x F\left(x\right)\:dx\tag{6}
\end{align}

Comment: Write out the case $n=1$.  Can you prove that case?  Then write out the case $n=2$.  Can you prove that case? Continue until you come to one you cannot prove.

Comment: @GEdgar I have edited it with trials with $n=1$ and $n=2$, but I'm stuck with that because I don't know how to evaluate the second integral. Am I messing something up?

Comment: For $n=1$.  You wrote the left side, $\int_0^x f\left(x\right)\:dx$.  Now write the right side.  See if they are equal.  For $n=2$ do this as well,  To see they are equal, interchange the order of integration.  Maybe using the same variable $x$ in each one is confusing...

Comment: @GEdgar I believe you are right, I'm going to try it a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to show that if $F(x) := \int_0^x f(t)\, dt$, then $$F^n(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^x (x - t)^{n-1}f(t)\, dt,$$

where $F^n$ is $\underbrace{F\circ F \circ \cdots \circ F}_{\text{$n$ times}}$. This can be proven by induction on $n$.

Since $\Gamma(1) = 1$, the statement when $n = 1$ is $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\, dt$, which holds by definition. Consider the $n = 2$ case. We have $$F^2(x) = F\left(\int_0^x f(t)\, dt\right) = \int_0^x \int_0^u f(t)\, dt\, du = \int_0^x \int_t^x f(t)\, du\, dt = \int_0^x (x - t)f(t)\, dt = \frac{1}{\Gamma(2)}\int_0^x (x - t)f(t)\, dt.$$ Now assume $n > 2$ and the result is true for $n$. Then

\begin{align}F^{n+1}(x) &= F(F^n(x)) = \int_0^x F^n(t)\, dt \\
&= \int_0^x \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_0^t (t - u)^{n-1} f(u)\, du\, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_0^x \int_u^x (t - u)^{n-1}\, dt\, du\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^x \frac{(x - u)^n}{n} f(u)\, du\\
&= \frac{1}{n\Gamma(n)} \int_0^x (x - u)^n f(u)\, du\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(n+1)} \int_0^x (x - u)^n f(u)\, du.
\end{align}

This shows that the result holds for $n+1$.

Note. $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ for all positive integers $n$. So you can write

$$F^n(x) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^x (x - t)^{n-1} f(t)\, dt.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looks great. I will study it and make sure I understand everything

Comment: I'm perplexed. In the first row of integrals for $n=2$ you have $$F^2\left(x\right)=F\left(\int_0^x f\left(t\right)\:dt\right)=\int_0^x\int_t^x f\left(t\right)\:du\:dt.$$ How are these all the same thing? If I integrate the last I'm left with $$\int_0^x\left[x f\left(t\right)-t f\left(t\right)\right]\:dt.$$

Comment: Well, $$ F^2(x) = F (F(x ))  = F\left(\int_0^x f(t)\, dt\right). $$ You skipped an intermediate step but that the integral you wrote is obtained by changing the order of integration.

Comment: Hmm...going further I see that $$ \int_0^x\left(xf\left(t\right)-t\left(t\right)\right]\:dt=\int_0^x xf\left(t\right)\:dt-\int_0^x tf\left(t\right)\:dt, $$ which then gives me $$ xF\left(x\right)-0-xF\left(x\right)-0+\int_0^x=\int_0^xF\left(t\right)\:dt. $$ But now what happens to this integral?

Comment: I don't see what you're trying to do. In computing $\int_0^x \int_t^x f(t)\, du\, dt$, first evaluate $\int_t^x f(t)\, du$. Since $f(t)$ is independent of $u$, $\int_t^x f(t)\, du = f(t)\int_t^x du = f(t)(x - t)$. So $\int_0^x \int_t^x f(t)\, du\, dt = \int_0^x (x - t)f(t)\, dt$.